# How to create a className from dynamic properties in reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs

Hi i have this myStyle object - but i have to apply class on h1 . How can i convert this myStyle into class.I tried this but its not working. its showing object when i inspect the elements.Height i am calculating dynamically based on the device height

```
class MyHeader extends React.Component {
deviceHeight=()=>document.height+"px";
  render() {
    const mystyle = {
      height: deviceHeight
      backgroundColor: "DodgerBlue",    };
    return (
      <div>
      <h1 className={mystyle}>Hello Style!</h1>
      <p>Add a little style!</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how color is related to height?

Comment: why you are not setting mystyle as style attribute for element?

Comment: Also there's a type you defined `mystyle` but implementing `myStyle`

Comment: @Ali Sattarzadeh Actually there are some situtions i have to add class only

Comment: 1. setting height as color is not correct. 2. adding mystyle constant variable to class attribute also will not affect. 3. you should use className instead class

Comment: @buzz - i just added sample here. there maybe spelling mistake

Comment: for this, you need to write CSS in this CSS file and give the className to the h1 tag

Comment: @PRADIPGORULE-  Actually height i am calculting in js file dynamically

Comment: @SADAMISLAMICvideos you're using `className` but it should be `style`

Comment: @buzz- i have to use class- How can i convert this object into className

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do this if you want to apply dynamic css then you can do it like this way. Add below tag in your jsx before the class tag you are trying it will genrate dynamic css in your component code and you can apply it.

```
<style>
      {`\
    .mystyle{\
      height:${deviceHeight}px;\
      background-color:'red'\
    }\
  `}
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `className` to `style`.
Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

Answer (score 0):

Here you are not giving the dynamic value for height so simple thing is to create one class write CSS for that class and add class to h1 tag

```
///CSS Code ///
.heading{
height: '20px';
backgroundColor: "DodgerBlue";
}
```

```
/// React code
class MyHeader extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h1 className='heading'>Hello Style!</h1>
      <p>Add a little style!</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code: `style={mystyle}`

if you want inject props to css codes you should use styled-component library: https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props

Comment: i have to use class . Not a style

Answer (score 0):

To use className to style your property what you can do is create a different css module and put your css stylings there

For example:

**Header.css**

```
.header {
  height: 100vh; //since you're using device height
  background: DodgerBlue
}
```

Now in your component import that css file

```
import styles from './Header.css';
```

Next in your `h1` tag

```
<h1 className={styles.header}>Hello Style!</h1>
```

this way you can use class name for styling.